# writing buffer to ofstream causes tellp() to point to the end of file

Tags: c++, ofstream

After calling `seekp()` to the middle of file, then writing my buffer, the file-pointer teleports to the end of file.

My code is more complex but essentially comes down to the following:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckFile(_mu_fileAccess);

   const char* buff = new const char[200];
   int preallocSize = 1024*512;

   _f.open(path_file_with_exten,  std::ios::app | std::ios::binary );
    if(!_f){ 
      delete[] buff;
      return; 
    }
    std::experimental::filesystem::resize_file(path_with_exten, preallocSize);
    _f.seekp(321, std::ios_base::beg);
    int64_t currPos = _f.tellp(); //will be 321
    _f.write(buff, 100);
    _f.tellp(); //somehow is equal to 1024*512 instead of 321+100
```

What might be causing this behavior? It occurs only in one specific place of my code. Other invocations of this code from other places work ok and don't teleport the pointer that far away.

I'm using C++14

**Edit:**

Following the below answer, I had to use `std::ios::ate` not `std::ios::app`.
However, I discovered that my file started to be re-created from scratch even though I'm not specifying `std::ios::trunc`.

I had to pass in additional flag `in` to make sure the file contents are preserved:

`auto flags = std::ios::ate | std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary; _f.open("myFile.exten", flags);`

otherwise [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/output-file-stream-member-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) says *"Creating a file. If the file already exists, the old version
is deleted."*

Comment: Well, what else did you expect `std::ios::app` to do? What is your C++ textbook's explanation for this flag?

Comment: I think `seekp()` moves the pointer away from the end of the file. I used `std::ios::app` so that the file contents aren't destroyed and by default the pointer is at the end of the file

Comment: Kari> This is not what `app` does. Here is a link to docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: @spectras I really struggled to find difference of app and ate. Please post this as an answer, I'll accept

Comment: No, that's not how a C++ textbook describes `std::ios::app`. It's not exactly for making sure "that the file contents aren't destroyed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comment above.

[Documentation for open modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)

> **app:**  seek to the end of stream before each write

Thus :

```
_f.write(buff, 100);
```

…triggers a seek to the end of the file before writing.

Comment: [And how to use and stack the open modes to get the behaviour you want](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)